How to get rid of the Google Login Popover
Each time I want to log into Stack Overflow, I have to get past the "Log in with your Goggle Account" (or whatever the English wording is):

But I never want that.
There cannot be a cookie to help, because I delete them frequently. So the Stack Overflow site is somewhat forced to show me the popover as it cannot know my preferences.
I tried to block the frame with uBlock Origin, but this makes the normal Login button unresponsive. Before digging into the depth of the page code, does someone happen to have a working solution already to block the frame which mostly blocks the Login button?
Alternatively a feature request: move the frame out of the way.

"but this makes the normal Login button unresponsive" - you probably blocked the wrong element, and left an invisible container

This is part of a recent change: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399057/upcoming-changes-to-sign-up-flow-on-the-stack-exchange-network

When I add stackoverflow.com###credential_picker_container to my uBlock rules I don't get the Google one-tap pop-up.

@rene Thanks, this is the answer. I was to timid to try the "cosmetic filters" section in uBo's element block picker.

I reflexively hit the X button on the screenshot as soon as the page loaded.

Sorry for the DV, put a question mark (in the Title) when asking a Qt... (You were not sharing a 'How-To'...) // Popup blocked without any Pb using 'uBlock' also... (On FF v122-v129)

When I add
stackoverflow.com###credential_picker_container 

to my uBlock rules (My Filters) I don't get the Google one-tap pop-up. The Login button still works as designed with this rule in place.
Tested on Firefox, Windows with uBlock 1.52.0

This is status-bydesign. Stack Exchange has recently made some changes to the sign-up flow part of which was to enable Google one-tap. Given this is part of the sign-up flow and if that prompt shows up you haven't signed in yet, Stack Exchange can't really provide you some preference / setting to enable / disable this.
As a workaround though you can opt out of One-tap on your end:

Users can opt out of One Tap if they disable the Google Account
sign-in prompts flag in the Apps with access to your
account page. The opted-out
sessions aren't shown in One Tap. If all Google sessions are opted
out, One Tap doesn't display.
If a user disables third-party sign-in on browsers with FedCM
enabled,
One Tap is not displayed. In Chrome settings under the Privacy and
Security section users control the display of third-party
sign-in prompts
either globally or for individual sites.

This obviously has the caveat though that you can't use this if you aren't signed in to google or aren't using a browser which has FedCM support (it is an experimental feature).

"This obviously has the caveat though that you can't use this if you aren't signed in to google". At least it is interesting how the responsibels at SO think that being constantly logged into Goorgle is normal.

I have had to add
||accounts.google.com/gsi/iframe/select
to “My filters” in uBlock Origin, because the div has different names on the Stack Exchange network (I have identified credential_picker_container, credentials_picker_container and credentials-picker-container).
